# Displaying label (boostrap badge) in an admin grid

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, jtable, highlighting

I need to display a green highlighted message in my grid.

I'm currently using `<span class="label label-success">message</span>`

Is there any way to do it via code like `JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('Message');` but for displaying a label/badge instead?

Comment: Have you tried this `JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('<span style="label label-success">' . $your-message . '</span>', 'message')`. You may be able to leave out the second argument `message` i'm not sure?

Comment: Thank you but i was looking for something that does it directly. Something like  `JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueBadge('danger');`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Could you not assign the span html to a php variable then use this variable in the enqueMessage?

Comment: Yeah. It's ok i will just use the span html without enqueMessage. Thank you @jonboy

Comment: Let us know if if works and we can add an answer for others